# replacing values in a nested tuple with the whole tuple

Tags: python, tuples, linguistics

Okay,

I am working on a linguistic prover, and I have series of tuples that represent statements or expressions.
Sometimes, I end up with an embedded "and" statement, and I am trying to "bubble" it up to the surface.
I want to take a tuple that looks like this:

```
('pred', ('and', 'a', 'b'), 'x')
```

or, for a more simple example:

```
( ('and', 'a', 'b'), 'x')
```

and I want to separate out the ands into two statements such that the top one results in:

```
('and', ('pred', 'a', 'x',), ('pred', 'b', 'x') )
```

and the bottom one in:

```
('and', ('a', 'x'), ('b', 'x') )
```

I've tried a lot of things, but it always turns out to be quite ugly code. And I am having problems if there are more nested tuples such as:

```
('not', ('p', ('and', 'a', 'b'), 'x') )
```

which I want to result in

```
('not', ('and', ('p', 'a', 'x',), ('p', 'b', 'x') ) )
```

So basically, the problem is trying to replace a nested tuple with the value of the entire tuple, but the nested one modified. It's very ugly. :(

I'm not super duper python fluent so it gets very convoluted with lots of for loops that I know shouldn't be there. :( 
Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Hard to work on these `tuples` with no real data type to use

Comment: sorry, everything inside them is a string. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Oh alright, I wasn't aware of that because there were no quotation marks and you said they were `tuples`

Comment: Ah, I just realized the representation is confusing. They're not quite tuples, but an Expression class whose __repr__ I modified to skip the commas in printing. I will fix that now. Thanks.

Comment: What's the desired outcome of `('not',('and','a','b'))`?  Should it become `('and',('not','a'),('not','b'))`, or `('or',('not','a'),('not','b'))`, or stay as it is?  Are there any other operators (?) with non-standard behavior? (i.e. that behave differently from the `( ('and', 'a', 'b'), 'x')` case?)

Comment: no, that can stay as it is. This is all already dealt with in pretty robust negation lowering code.

What I am trying to correct for is the case where the and/or is buried such that the negation lowering can't get to it. And then this will handlable.

Comment: And no, and/or is all I'm worried about in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This recursive approach seems to work.

```
def recursive_bubble_ands_up(expr):
    """ Bubble all 'and's in the expression up one level, no matter how nested.
    """
    # if the expression is just a single thing, like 'a', just return it. 
    if is_atomic(expr):
        return expr
    # if it has an 'and' in one of its subexpressions 
    #  (but the subexpression isn't just the 'and' operator itself)
    #  rewrite it to bubble the and up
    and_clauses = [('and' in subexpr and not is_atomic(subexpr)) 
                   for subexpr in expr]
    if any(and_clauses):
        first_and_clause = and_clauses.index(True)
        expr_before_and = expr[:first_and_clause]
        expr_after_and = expr[first_and_clause+1:]
        and_parts = expr[first_and_clause][1:]
        expr = ('and',) + tuple([expr_before_and + (and_part,) + expr_after_and 
                                 for and_part in and_parts])
    # apply recursive_bubble_ands_up to all the elements and return result
    return tuple([recursive_bubble_ands_up(subexpr) for subexpr in expr])

def is_atomic(expr):
    """ Return True if expr is an undividable component 
    (operator or value, like 'and' or 'a'). """
    # not sure how this should be implemented in the real case, 
    #  if you're not really just working on strings
    return isinstance(expr, str)
```

Works on all your examples:

```
>>> tmp.recursive_bubble_ands_up(('pred', ('and', 'a', 'b'), 'x'))
('and', ('pred', 'a', 'x'), ('pred', 'b', 'x'))
>>> tmp.recursive_bubble_ands_up(( ('and', 'a', 'b'), 'x'))
('and', ('a', 'x'), ('b', 'x'))
>>> tmp.recursive_bubble_ands_up(('not', ('p', ('and', 'a', 'b'), 'x') ))
('not', ('and', ('p', 'a', 'x'), ('p', 'b', 'x')))
```

Note that this isn't aware of any other "special" operators, like `not` - as I said in my comment, I'm not sure what it should do with that.  But it should give you something to start with.

**Edit:** Oh, oops, I just realized this only performs a single "bubble-up" operation, for example:

```
>>> tmp.recursive_bubble_ands_up(((('and', 'a', 'b'), 'x'), 'y' ))
(('and', ('a', 'x'), ('b', 'x')), 'y')
>>> tmp.recursive_bubble_ands_up((('and', ('a', 'x'), ('b', 'x')), 'y'))
('and', (('a', 'x'), 'y'), (('b', 'x'), 'y'))
```

So what you really want is probably to apply it in a while loop until the output is identical to the input, if you want your 'and' to bubble up from however many levels, like this:

```
def repeat_bubble_until_finished(expr):
    """ Repeat recursive_bubble_ands_up until there's no change 
    (i.e. until all possible bubbling has been done). 
    """
    while True:
        old_expr = expr
        expr = recursive_bubble_ands_up(old_expr)
        if expr == old_expr:
            break
    return expr
```

On the other hand, doing that shows that actually my program breaks your 'not' example, because it bubbles the 'and' ahead of the 'not', which you said you wanted left alone:

```
>>> tmp.recursive_bubble_ands_up(('not', ('p', ('and', 'a', 'b'), 'x')))
('not', ('and', ('p', 'a', 'x'), ('p', 'b', 'x')))
>>> tmp.repeat_bubble_until_finished(('not', ('p', ('and', 'a', 'b'), 'x')))
('and', ('not', ('p', 'a', 'x')), ('not', ('p', 'b', 'x')))
```

So I suppose you'd have to build in a special case for 'not' into `recursive_bubble_ands_up`, or just apply your not-handling function before running mine, and insert it before `recursive_bubble_ands_up` in `repeat_bubble_until_finished` so they're applied in alternation.

All right, I really should sleep now.

Comment: I did make a couple of small changes: 
-First, the and_clauses gathering should be reversed so that the is_atomic short-circuits. i.e.: [(not is_atomic(subexpr) and 'and' in subexpr) for subexpr in expr]
-Second, I added a line after the first is_atomic check to make sure that the main phrase isn't an "and" (or a not) because that currently looped forever in situations like: repeat_bubble_until_finished(parse_expr("(p (and x y) (and a b))"))
(i.e. if expr[0] in ('and', 'not'):
        return Expr([recursive_bubble_ands_up(subexpr) for subexpr in expr]) )

Comment: But thanks again! This is so much more elegant than what I was trying. Python is very nifty.

Comment: Oh, good point! Yeah, I forgot about the duplicate "and" case, thanks for pointing that out! It was after midnight. ;)  Anyway, glad I gave you something to work with!  It was fun to write. Python is pretty nifty, yes.